# Truncate a value in an array of objects javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

How do I go about truncating a value in an array of objects?

Lets say:

```
var items = [
{
  name: "CN=arun, hjsdhjashdj,jsdhjsa,kshd",
  status: "Present"
}, {
  name: "CN=manohar, abcdefghij,111111,2222222",
  status: "Present"
}, {
  name: "manohar",
  status: "Absent"
}]
```

How do I go about truncating the value only if a CN is present and update the items array with the new ones?

The updated array I need should look like this:

```
var items = [
{
  name: "CN=arun...",
  status: "Present"
}, {
  name: "CN=manohar...",
  status: "Present"
}, {
  name: "manohar",
  status: "Absent"
}]
```

So basically, I check whether the string contains a "CN=" substring and truncate it at the first comma and add "..." then update the same array like forEach does.

Comment: seems like a simple loop over the array and checking to see if the property starts with the string and replacing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can loop, check for the presence of `CN=`, split on the first comma, then add your truncate `...`

```
items.forEach(i => {
    if (i.name.indexOf("CN=") > -1) {
        i.name = i.name.split(",")[0] + "...";
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You could replace the unwanted parts.

```js
function update(o) {
    o.name = o.name.replace(/,.*$/, '...');
}

var items = [{ name: "CN=arun, hjsdhjashdj,jsdhjsa,kshd", status: "Present" }, { name: "CN=manohar, abcdefghij,111111,2222222", status: "Present" }, { name: "manohar", status: "Absent" }];

items.forEach(update);

console.log(items);
```

Answer (score 1):

use String methods..

```js
var items = [
{
  name: "CN=arun, hjsdhjashdj,jsdhjsa,kshd",
  status: "Present"
}, {
  name: "CN=manohar, abcdefghij,111111,2222222",
  status: "Present"
}, {
  name: "manohar",
  status: "Absent"
}];
items.forEach(function(item){
  if(item.name.includes('CN=')){
    var values = item.name.split(',');
    item.name = values[0] + '...';
  }
});

console.log(items);
```